# when stanford-nlp OpenIE extract incorrect information from sentence?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

in OpenIE System in stanford-nlp when enter some Sentence it's can Extract a correct information and anther Sentence my be failed to extract the information 
if there any rules to write the Sentence ?
if i want to extract a specific information it's possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other statistical system, OpenIE has a certain accuracy that's somewhere less than 100%. You should not expect it to work on every sentence perfectly. If you notice a systematic class of mistakes that it makes, I'd be happy to take a look and see if I can do anything to improve the system.